# Entity Framework: The instance of entity type '<T>' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: x}' is already being tracked

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, change-tracking

I have a controller which calls the `ChangeActivity` method, the `source` and `destination` is gained using another dbContext than what is used here.
All code can be found [here](https://github.com/theodor349/WeeklyReview/blob/feature/changeActivity/WeeklyReviewSource/WeeklyReview/Shared/Services/ActivityChangeService.cs).

I also have a lot of unit tests which also test aginst an SQL Server database, and they do not encounter this problem.

Models

```cs
public class EntryModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public List<ActivityModel> Activities { get; set; }
   ...
}

public class ActivityModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Problematic Code

```cs
public ActivityChangeModel ChangeActivity(ActivityModel source, ActivityModel destination, Guid userGuid)
{
    DeleteActivity(source);
    OverrideEntries(source, destination, userGuid);

    var change = AddChange(source, destination, userGuid);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return change;
}

private void DeleteActivity(ActivityModel source)
{
    var model = _db.Activity.Single(x => x.Id == source.Id);
    model.Deleted = true;
}

private void OverrideEntries(ActivityModel source, ActivityModel destination, Guid userGuid)
{
    var entries = _db.Entry.Include(x => x.Activities).Where(x => x.Activities.Contains(source)).ToList();
    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        entry.Deleted = true;
    }

    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        var newEntry = new EntryModel(entry.StartTime, entry.EndTime, entry.RecordedTime, new List<ActivityModel>(), false, userGuid);
        _db.Entry.Add(newEntry);

        var activities = entry.Activities;
        activities.Remove(source);
        activities.Add(destination);
        newEntry.Activities = activities;
    }
}

private ActivityChangeModel AddChange(ActivityModel source, ActivityModel destination, Guid userGuid)
{
    var change = new ActivityChangeModel(source, destination, _timeService.Current, userGuid);
    _db.ActivityChange.Add(change); // Throws Error
    return change;
}
```

The error which is thrown is

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'ActivityModel' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 5}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'

I have tried

- Using `_db.ChangeTracker.Clear();` before I add the activity to activities
- Looking at the changes with `_db.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView` just before `var activities = entry.Activities;` which says that the activity `Id: 5` is being tracked, but it is unchanged

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The object is already loaded. Instead of trying to remove it and replace it with another, apply any changes to the loaded object

Comment: BTW calling `_db.SaveChanges();` after every call is a *major* bug, which breaks DbContext's transaction behavior. A DbContext is a Unit of Work, not a database connection. `SaveChanges` is used to commit all pending changes and should only be called at the very end of a business operation or controller action, right before disposing the DbContext itself. If you don't call it, the changes are discarded

Comment: In this question's code, `SaveChanges` should only be called at the very end of `ChangeActivity` if not later. Wherever the scope of the DbContext itself ends.

Comment: What is this code trying to do anyway? "Soft-delete" the entire Entry that has a specific activity? That's rarely a good idea and never the actual business requirement. In this case, the code is trying to *insert* an identical entry without removing the previous one. Setting some property to `True` doesn't delete the original entity

Comment: Removing all `_db.SaveChanges()` s.t. it is only called at the end of `ChangeActivity`, moves the error to the second line of `AddChange` (I have updated the question to reflect this)

Comment: Using `SaveChanges` multiple times is a different but very serious bug. The original bug is trying to add a new entry instead of modifying the existing one. Again, what are you trying to do? A soft delete? Generate audit entries? It almost looks like you're trying to run trigger code on the client. EF Core is an ORM, not a replacement for ADO.NET, raw SQL or triggers. Its job is to let you work with objects instead of tables and rows.

Comment: Yea I found the error, I had forgotten that the input `destination` is not tracked by the current `dbContext`

Comment: What it is supposed to do is: 
1. Delete the old entry (Well I should be able to restore it later if needed)
2. Create a new one in its place, which replaces the `source` activity with the `destination`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why I get the error is that the `soruce` and `destination` objects that `ChangeActivity` recieves is retrived using another `dbContext`.
This means that when `destination` is retrived from the current `dbContext` we now have two equvilent `destination`, one which is tracked by the new `dbContext` and another which is not.

The fix is then to either override `soruce` and `destination` by `_db.Activity.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == source.Id)` or in my case change the `dbContext` to be scoped instead of a transiant service.
Changing it to scoped, means that the two `destination` objects we had before, are now the same one and tracked by the `dbContext`. ([Here](https://github.com/theodor349/WeeklyReview/commit/723ff3c44f2d19f7279824a388d64375cb03a793) is the changes I made)

Answer (score 0):

I Faced this issue time ago and i resolved used dbContextFactory instead dbContext.

here the approch

**on Program.cs** add context factory and remove reference to tb context

```
services.AddDbContextFactory<MyContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnection")));
```

**Inside service class add the following code**

```
public class MyServiceClass: IMyServiceClass
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<MyContext> _contextFactory;


    public MyServiceClass(IConfiguration config, IDbContextFactory<MyContext> contextFactory)
    {
        _config = config;
        _contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }
...
```

**Then i modify the methods**

```
    private void DeleteActivity(ActivityModel source)
    {
        using (var ctx = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            var model = ctx.Activity.Single(x => x.Id == source.Id);
            model.Deleted = true;
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    private void OverrideEntries(ActivityModel source, ActivityModel destination, Guid userGuid)
    {

        using (var ctx = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            var entries = ctx.Entry.Include(x => x.Activities).Where(x => x.Activities.Contains(source)).ToList();
            foreach (var entry in entries)
            {
                entry.Deleted = true;
            }
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
        using (var ctx = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            foreach (var entry in entries)
            {
                var entries = ctx.Entry.Include(x => x.Activities).Where(x => x.Activities.Contains(source)).ToList();

                var newEntry = new EntryModel(entry.StartTime, entry.EndTime, entry.RecordedTime, new List<ActivityModel>(), false, userGuid);
                ctx.Entry.Add(newEntry);

                var activities = entry.Activities;
                activities.Remove(source);
                activities.Add(destination);
                newEntry.Activities = activities;
                ctx.SaveChanges(); // Throws Error
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the reasoning behind `UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking))`? Is this not just a hack, and not the "propper" way to do it?

Comment: i'm sorry i just copy my code, but i forgot to remove this part of code, for this isuue is not the right way, i modify the code. But it work fine withouth the hack.

Answer (score -1):

To resolve this issue, you can detach the `ActivityModel` entity before attaching it again in the `OverrideEntries` method.You can use the `DbContext.Entry()` method to explicitly detach the entity from the context. Here is the sample implementation:

```
private void OverrideEntries(ActivityModel source, ActivityModel destination, Guid userGuid)
{
    //your code here

    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        // Detach the source activity from the context
        _db.Entry(source).State = EntityState.Detached;

        var newEntry = new EntryModel(entry.StartTime, entry.EndTime, entry.RecordedTime, new List<ActivityModel>(), false, userGuid);
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: This tries to cover up the bug but will result in a duplicate key error from the database, when EF tries to INSERT the Added entries with the same PK as existing rows. The real bug remains - trying to insert duplicate entities

Comment: No PK mentioned on question and sample code @PanagiotisKanavos . Please check the question.

Comment: The very bug complains about the primary key values, so yes, that's the root of the problem. You removed the code that *attaches* the entry but there's no way to avoid problems - if you attach as Modified, there won't be any new entry. If you attach as Added, you'll get a PK violation. You'd have to *delete* the old entry to insert the new one

Comment: "DB Context is being shared by multiple requests" is different with "PK violation". The issue is first one, not PK violation. Asker said in comment that the problem is "destination was not being tracked" which can't be found in source code that shared by asker.

Comment: I'll have to say `please check the question` myself. Check the actual error. `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'ActivityModel' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 5}' is already being tracked.`